# How can I make a variable's name from another variable AND string?

Tags: php, variable-variables

Say I had the variable `$foo` which has a value of `"bar"` and I wanted to make a variable variable from it, but also append the string `"123"` to it, so that the variable name is `$bar123`. How would I do this?

I already know that `$$foo = "abc123"` would make a variable `$bar` with the value of `"abc123"`, but I don't know how to append a string to this variable name.

Comment: they are called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), and are almost always a bad idea. very often an array is the better solution

Comment: @smith I already know about variable variables but I don't know how to use them AND append a string to the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the solution was fairly simple:

```
$foo = "bar";
$x = $foo . "123"
$$x = "random important variable value"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), you can do something as the following:

```
<?php

 $a = "foo";
 $number = 123;
 $b = $a . "$number";

 $$b = "Hello World!";

 echo ${$b};
```

However, as @smith said, it is better to use associative arrays here.